# 2.8 UV editing, can't box select polygons in 3D viewport anymore

Tags: uv, selection-tools

I am UV mapping a low poly model and my workflow involves a lot of box-select, select linked and moving the polys in the UV window. **Until recently** this worked fine. Now I can't box-select in the right hand 3D viewport (see below). I've been through all the menus and I can't find anything obvious.

If I go to the modeling workspace, then it works fine but skipping back and forth is not an option.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). There seem to be some minor issues with workspace behavior. The solution is usually to delete the workspace and create it again :).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to delete the UV Editing workspace and make a new one.

Big thanks to [Jachym Michal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/78972/jachym-michal) for the solution in a comment.

### Steps

- On the tabs across the top of the window (these are Workspaces), right click on UV Editing
- Select delete

[image: The right click drop down on the UV Edit]

- Click the [+] icon on the right of the workspace tabs
- Navigate to General ➡ UV Editing

[image: The add workspace button]

You'll have a new UV Editing Workspace. You might need to zoom in on your UV and re-apply any 3D viewport settings you had.